# How to fix extremely slow Virtualbox network download speed?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm using an Ubuntu 12.04 VM (hashicorp/precise32) via Vagrant/Virtualbox. It seems to have an exremely slow download speed compared to my host system. This is what I get with the host system (OSX) with speedtest-cli:

```
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 845.62 Mbits/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 296.03 Mbits/s
```

And this is what I get in the guest OS (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 12.41 Mbits/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 247.64 Mbits/s
```

So host download speed is 70 times faster! The usual response to these issues is this:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
end
```

But I have already configured it to my Vagrantfile.

I also tested this with plain Virtualbox and 12.04 (no Vagrant). The same issue occurs when I use NAT interface. However, switching to bridged mode makes the download speed 20x faster. This is nasty, since Vagrant relies on the NAT interface to be always eth0.

I use OSX Mavericks as the host system. Virtualbox version is 4.3.18.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

For vagrant users, add the following to your Vagrant file:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
end
```

I got a speed boost of ~15x. On VirtualBox GUI I see now a different Adapter Type for my NAT interface: `Paravirtualized Network (virtio-net)`.

Comment: I had the same issue: the upload speed on a Boot2Docker image running on Vagrant, as measured using speedtest-cli, was 0 (so slow you can't measure it?). As soon as I added this setting, the upload speed matched the speed of my host OS. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know what are all the other possible values ? Any link to the docs ?

Comment: no improvement for me I'm afraid. Vagrant 1.7.4, Virtualbox 5.0.4

Comment: All possible options are here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp46730496367936
Try `Am79C973` too if you have problems with `virtio`.

Comment: VBoxManage modifyvm YourMachineName --nictype1 virtio

Answer (score 19):

I have found mach simpler solution for me

- Host ubuntu 14.04
- guest ubuntu 14.04
- Nat with port forwarding
- extremely slow upload speed from guest. It was so slow that speed test even cant measure that.

I just switched to PCNet-Fast III adapter. And speed become good enough for me (40 Mb/s)

Comment: Worked for me with Host Ubuntu 14.04 and Guest Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: To switch to PCNet Fast III in Vagrantfile, use `v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "Am79C973"]`.

Comment: This works great! I was having trouble with `apt-get` hanging while trying to download. Eventually it would work, but changing the network adapter as above sorts the problem out.

Comment: Worked with Win10 host running Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 0):

@auramo's answer is useful, but please note that it specifies a specific NIC: #1. In my system, for instance, I have numerous Network Interfaces. I had to specify `--nictype4`.

As well, others have reported benefits elsewhere of specifying `natdnshostresolver#` and `natdnsproxy#` where `#` is a number identifying your NIC. In mine, it looks like this:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype4", "virtio"]
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver4", "on"]
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy4", "on"]
end
```